# Hibernate Envers: usage of 'in' in the query

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have three Tables `A`, `B`, and `AB`. AB table is a relationship table. So `AB_AUD` table has `abID` as PK, and `aId`, `bID`, Revision Info. 
I've got list of 'bIds' and would like to retrieve audit data from `AB_AUD` table using the list. My code block is

```
AuditQuery query = auditReader.createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(AB.class, false, true)
    .add(AuditEntity.property("bId").in(bIds))
    .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc());
```

**This throws exception :could not resolve property of bId**. Even I tried equating with single `bId` to retrieve audit data for a single `bId` which threw same `exception`.
I would like to know if there is any mistake in the code. For now I am doing a for loop to retrieve data like this:

```
for (B b : listofB's)
{
    AuditQuery query = auditReader.createQuery()
        .forRevisionsOfEntity(AB.class, false, true)
        .add(AuditEntity.property("b").eq(b))
        .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc());
}
```

Which runs `sql query` for every B, which isn't a good way.

Answer (score 0):

If your property name is `b` then why are you using `bId` in the query.  Update the query to use `b` as below:

```
            .forRevisionsOfEntity(AB.class, false, true)
             .add(AuditEntity.property("b").in(istofB's))
             .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc());
```

This should work.

Comment: AuditEntity.property("b").in(istofB's) didn't work ,I feel comparing property b to a list of objects is causing error. Generating sql query based on bId should also retrieve audit data as bId is the column in AB table.Please advise.

Comment: Desn't sound right. Did you still get error saying property `b` undefined?